# Multiply responses from different webservice calls

Tags: angular, web-services, response, chaining

Upon the completition of this chain, I would like to show the result of val3 multiplied by val5.

This is now my mock services structure look like:

```
{
  "person": [{
    "val1": 1,
    "val2": 2
  }],
  "facility": [{
    "val3": 3,
    "val4": 4
  }],
  "exposure": [{
    "val5": 5
  }]
}
```

And this is the component, where I am calling the services in a chain.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './entities/person';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  apiUrl1: string = 'http://localhost:3000/person/?';
  apiUrl2: string = 'http://localhost:3000/facility/?';
  apiUrl3: string = 'http://localhost:3000/exposure/?';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getData(arg): Observable<any> {
    return (this.http.get(this.apiUrl1 + arg)
      .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + response.val1))
      .flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + response.val2))
      )
  }

}
```

Comment: `import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';` probably unrelated to the question, but this import is wrong, use `import {Observable} from 'rxjs'`

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is what you want? (Rxjs uses a pipe() method). You only need to map the response as your output by multiplying the values how you want.

```
getData(arg): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl1 + arg).pipe(
    flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + response.val1)),
    flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + response.val2)),
    map((response: any) => response.val3 * response.val5)
  )
}
```

Note that this only returns a number. So if you need the response in other ways too, subscribe to it instead:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.getData(arg).subscribe(result => {
    const output = result.val3 * response.val5;
  });
}

getData(arg): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl1 + arg).pipe(
    flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl2 + response.val1)),
    flatMap((response: any) => this.http.get(this.apiUrl3 + response.val2))
  )
}
```

Comment: this way I get: `Cannot find name map, flatMap`, even if I import  the following way: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: btw I am not using the newest version of redux, it might be because of that.

Comment: Try `import {map, flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`